# How can I add MouseOver action to this view?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an ajax button just like this now.

```
<% if current_user.following?(user) %>
  <%= link_to(unfollow_user_path(user), :remote => true, :class => 'btn') do %>
    Now Following
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to(follow_user_path(user) ,:remote => true, :class => 'btn btn-primary') do %>
    Follow
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I bring the mouse cursor over the button that's showing "Now Following", I want to show this.

```
<%= link_to(follow_user_path(user) ,:remote => true, :class => 'btn btn-danger') do %>
  Un-Follow
<% end %>
```

How can I apply this to my view with MouseOver condition? (Only when it's showing "Now Following")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, do the following:

```
# change the class in your link:
link_to(unfollow_user_path(user), remote: true, class: 'btn now-following') do ... end

# add this code in a file under app/assets/javascripts/
$('.now-following').on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).addClass('btn-danger').text('Un-Follow');
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-danger').text('Now Following');
    }
});
```

I usually write in CoffeeScript so hopefully the above is correct :)

Comment: I'd like to know how to do that with your 2nd suggestion. Please tell me how to with that one:)

Comment: your code won't show `:class => 'btn btn-danger'` which will make it red colored. Where should it be?

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that part. Have a look at my answer now.

Comment: Thanks. Please let me try it:)

Comment: I tried what exactly you told me. However, nothing happens when I bring mouse cursor over the button:( I'm check web console, too.

Comment: I finally realized you wanted to change the text as well, I've updated my code. It should be working, have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/mind_blank/6TGPn/7/